# Magento 2 : Is there any way to stop to sending email to customer while importing customer?

Tags: magento2, customer, email, import

Is there any way to stop to sending email to customer while importing customer ?

Is `Disable Email Communication : OFF` this helpful for that ?

Comment: How you import the customer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **stop sending the email during  Customer import** then you have to work on `Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification:newAccount()`.

Create an around plugin on `Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification:newAccount()` 
 **method and stop execute of this method**.

And add **Import Url full Action** name as a **condition on this plugin**.

### Plugin Class

```
<?php

namespace Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification as CustomerEmailNotification;

class EmailNotification {

    protected $request;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function aroundNewAccount(
        CustomerEmailNotification $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,    
        CustomerInterface $customer,
        $type = CustomerEmailNotification::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED,
        $backUrl = '',
        $storeId = 0,
        $sendemailStoreId = null
    ) {

        $action = $this->request->getFullActionName();
        // if import URL  Full Action pathc then  donot excute rest of
        //  all code
        if($action == 'MY_ACTION_FULLNAME'){
            return $subject;
        }
        return $proceed(
                $customer,
                $type,
                $backUrl,
                $storeId,
                $sendemailStoreId
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am importing customers using magento's default import feature, How do I stop mail sending during import process